# WCF services, loading data from database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, wcf, wcf-data-services

I have some problem with WCF services in asp.net mvc application.
Help me please!
When I run my project some data for some entities are loading from database, but some data are not loading(Internal server error).

Code and description of exceptions:

EntityTypeController:

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetAll()
{
       //for debug
       var t = EntityTypeService.GetAll();

       //some exception here!
       /*
    The request channel timed out while waiting for a reply after 00:00:59.9979999. 
    Increase the timeout value passed to the call to Request or increase the SendTimeout value on the Binding. 
    The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.
    */
    //SendTimeout is 00:30:00 for all services.

    or

    /*The underlying connection was closed: A connection that was expected to be kept alive was closed by the server.*/

    or

    /*An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to http://localhost:18822/Services/Department.svc. 
    This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an 
    HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details.*/


       return CreateResponse<IEnumerable<EntityType>>(EntityTypeService.GetAll);
}
```

EntityTypeService:

```
public class EntityTypeService : BaseService<Base.Entities.EntityType>, IEntityTypeService
{
        public IQueryable<Base.Entities.EntityType> GetAll()
        {
            var t = Repository.Get();
            return t;
        }
}
```

Repository:

```
public class Repository<TEntity>: IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity: BaseEntity
{
        [Inject]
        public IDataContext Context { get; set; }

        [Inject]
        public IDatabase DataSource { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get entities from repository
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="filter">Filter</param>
        /// <param name="orderBy">Order by property</param>
        /// <param name="includeProperties"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public virtual IQueryable<TEntity> Get(
            Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
            Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
            string includeProperties = "")
        {
            var query = Context.Set<TEntity>().AsQueryable();

            // Apply filter
            filter.Do((s) => { 
                query = query.Where(filter); 
            });


            // Apply includes
            foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties.Split(new [] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
            {
                query = query.Include(includeProperty);
            }

            // Apply order by if need

            var result = orderBy
                .With(x => x(query))
                .Return(x => x, query);


            return result;
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Find entity by key
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="id">Identificator</param>
        /// <returns>Entity</returns>
        public virtual TEntity GetById(object id)
        {
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
            return Context.Set<TEntity>().Find(id);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Add new entity to repository
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="entity">New entity</param>
        public virtual void Insert(TEntity entity)
        {
            AttachIsNotAttached(entity);
            Context.Set<TEntity>().Add(entity);
            Context.SaveChanges();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Updated entity in repositoy
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="entity">Entity</param>
        public virtual void Update(TEntity entity)
        {
            AttachIsNotAttached(entity);
            Context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;            
            Context.SaveChanges();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Remove entity from rpository
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="entity">Entity</param>
        public virtual void Delete(TEntity entity)
        {
            AttachIsNotAttached(entity);
            Context.Set<TEntity>().Remove(entity);
            Context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Deleted;
            Context.SaveChanges();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Return models error
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public IEnumerable<object> GetValidationModelErrors()
        {
            return Context.GetValidationErrors();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Attach entity 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="entity"></param>
        protected void AttachIsNotAttached(TEntity entity)
        {
            if (Context.Entry(entity).State == EntityState.Detached)
            {
                var attached = Context.Set<TEntity>().Local.Where(x => x.Id == entity.Id).FirstOrDefault();

                attached.Do((s) => {
                    Context.Entry(s).State = EntityState.Detached;
                });

                Context.Set<TEntity>().Attach(entity);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Debug the service or turn on [diagnostics](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2007/Dec/09/Tracing-WCF-Messages) to get the specific error details. 500 Internal server error is useless.

Answer (score 0):

By default the wcf config has many limitations like the max size of array, and the exception doesnt exactly what happens,maybe in your case it's due to the default wcf config, I advice you to use [svcTraceViewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023.aspx), it will help you a lot to understand what happen exactly with an explicit messages.